# Is it possible to change the OS in the EV3 Mindstorm Brick

Tags: ev3, programming

I'd like to know how to change the OS embedded into the EV3 mindstorm Brick ( list of it ).
For example, would it be possible to replace the existing one by a linux release without losing any functionality ?

I want to to use an OS supporting all the Robot EV3 functionalities and also the 802.15.4 protocol.

Comment: See also [Is it safe to try different firmwares on EV3](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/2445/56)

Answer (score 5):

This can usually be achieved on the EV3 with a [bootable SD](http://sourceforge.net/p/lejos/wiki/Creating%20a%20bootable%20SD%20card/) card - you would set that up with a new firmware image and a loader that copies it across to the brick.

The [leJOS team](http://sourceforge.net/p/lejos/wiki/Getting%20started%20with%20leJOS%20EV3/) have ported their codebase to the EV3 - so with a bootable SD card you can indeed load a modified version of the firmware onto your EV3 brick.

You can then use their [WiFi stack](http://sourceforge.net/p/lejos/wiki/Configuring%20Wifi/) to communicate with your brick via a USB dongle - whether they support 802.15.4 yet (or ever will) I couldn't say.

> The WiFi stack is loaded to allow connection to the EV3 via a supported USB WiFi adaptor. This allows you to connect to the EV3 via Telnet, SSH and NFS and makes program development very simple.

Answer (score 4):

I am working on a project called [ev3dev](https://github.com/mindboards/ev3dev) that runs Debian on the EV3. We are not quite to the point that we support "all the Robot EV3 functionalities", but we are getting very close. We are also using a version 3.3.0 Linux kernel, which is more up to date than the other EV3 firmware projects that I know of (which use a 2.6.33 kernel). If you would like to propose that we add 802.15.4 support, just create a new [issue](https://github.com/mindboards/ev3dev/issues). We welcome anyone who who would like to contribute.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer, David. I have followed your suggestion and have submitted an issue for the 802.15.4 protocole support

Comment: Could you please specify shat do ou mean when you say that you "We are not quite to the point that we support "all the Robot EV3 functionalities"? What functionalities are missing at this time? Is there any work around? Could you please let me know if it will be show stopper for me?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: > We are not quite to the point that we support "all the Robot EV3 functionalities"

means that we are pretty much re-writing the drivers from the ground up. We are getting ready to do a release soon (week or two maybe) that will allow you to use most sensors. Motor support is still in development, but we will have minimal support at least. You can have a look at the wiki at the link I provided to see how to use everything.

Comment: Hello David,
I've seen that you have updated the motor’s functionality and I am wondering if you could let me know which release I should download and experiment to be able to use this motor. 
Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: My latest release is [here](https://github.com/dlech/ev3dev/releases), although it does not have Ralph's latest motor driver changes yet. It does have basic motor control though. If you have any more questions about ev3dev, just post a new issue on github.